# Fully managed enrollment with Android Management API on active device

Tags: android, mdm, android-management-api

Is it possible to enroll a fully managed device with Android Management API that does not have a fresh install?  I can only get a work profile installed.

Answer (score 1):

Fully Managed can only be initialised from Setup Wizard I'm afraid. The factory reset requirement is important to ensure the device is uncompromised before enabling Fully Managed mode.

Here is a [list of available provisioning methods](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#provisioning_methods) you can use to enrol a fully managed device.